# PyQt: slot is called many times

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I have created a custom widget using Qt Designer. With the use of pyuic, I converted the .ui file to a .py file. My intention is simple: I need to find out which radio button has been chosen.

Here is the Designer converted python script `ui_persistence_size.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'persistance_size2.ui'
#
# Created: Fri Dec 19 00:57:01 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(449, 129)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.size_256 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_256.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 81, 22))
        self.size_256.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_256"))
        self.size_512 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_512.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 81, 22))
        self.size_512.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_512"))
        self.size_768 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_768.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(179, 30, 81, 22))
        self.size_768.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_768"))
        self.size_1gb = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_1gb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(262, 30, 81, 22))
        self.size_1gb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_1gb"))
        self.size_2gb = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_2gb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(352, 30, 81, 22))
        self.size_2gb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_2gb"))
        self.size_3gb = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_3gb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 81, 22))
        self.size_3gb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_3gb"))
        self.size_4gb = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.size_4gb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 81, 22))
        self.size_4gb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("size_4gb"))
        self.choose = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.choose.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 68, 96, 26))
        self.choose.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("choose"))
        self.cancel = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.cancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 68, 96, 26))
        self.cancel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cancel"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Persistence Size Chooser...", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Choose Persistence Size..", None))
        self.size_256.setText(_translate("Dialog", "256MB", None))
        self.size_512.setText(_translate("Dialog", "512MB", None))
        self.size_768.setText(_translate("Dialog", "768GB", None))
        self.size_1gb.setText(_translate("Dialog", "1GB", None))
        self.size_2gb.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2GB", None))
        self.size_3gb.setText(_translate("Dialog", "3GB", None))
        self.size_4gb.setText(_translate("Dialog", "4GB", None))
        self.choose.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>Choose selected persistance size...</p></body></html>", None))
        self.choose.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Choose", None))
        self.cancel.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>Do not choose anything and close the window.</p></body></html>", None))
        self.cancel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel", None))
```

Here is the main script, `persistence.py`, that I am working on:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from ui_persistence_size import Ui_Dialog
import sys
import var

class PersistenceGui(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

    #def __init__(self):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.cancel.clicked.connect(self.on_close_clicked)
        self.ui.choose.clicked.connect(self.on_choose_clicked)

    def on_close_clicked(self):
        print "No persistence size choosen."
        QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()

    def on_choose_clicked(self):
        if self.ui.size_256.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "256"
        elif self.ui.size_512.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "512"
        elif self.ui.size_768.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "768"
        elif self.ui.size_1gb.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "1gb"
        elif self.ui.size_2gb.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "2gb"
        elif self.ui.size_3gb.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "3gb"
        elif self.ui.size_4gb.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "4gb"
            print "Selected" + var.persistence_size
            QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()
        else:

            print "Please choose persistence size..."
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'No size...', 'No persistence size selected.\n\nPlease choose persistence size and click Choose.')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = PersistenceGui()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I execute the main script, I found two issues. One is that except for one radio button (256MB - 3GB), nothing works; and when I choose the last radio button (4GB) the code is getting repeated three times.

```
$ ./persistence.py
Selected4gb
Selected4gb
Selected4gb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the output is being printed three times, is because of the way you named the signal handlers. The [connect slots by name feature](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name) will automatically connect signal handlers that are named using the following format:

```
    on_[object name]_[signal name]
```

Since the `clicked` signal has *two* overloads, and you added an explicit connection yourself, that makes three connections in total.

The easiest way to fix this, is to change the names of your handlers to something like this:

```
        self.ui.cancel.clicked.connect(self.handleCloseClicked)
        self.ui.choose.clicked.connect(self.handleChooseClicked)

    def handleCloseClicked(self):
    ...

    def handleChooseClicked(self):
    ...
```

The other issue is caused by incorrect handling of the `if/elif` block. It should probably look more like this:

```
        ...
        elif self.ui.size_4gb.isChecked():
            var.persistence_size = "4gb"
        else:
            print "Please choose persistence size..."
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'No size...', 'No persistence size selected.\n\nPlease choose persistence size and click Choose.')
            return
        print "Selected", var.persistence_size
        QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Accepted the answer. Thank you.